# Is it now possible to visit the UK for tourism on an exsiting multiple entry business visa?

Tags: visas, uk, change-purpose-of-travel

I am a British citizen residing in South Africa. In June I will be visiting family in the UK accompanied by my South African wife who holds a valid C Business visa (expiring in 2018). Under the new regulations, can my wife use her existing visa to enter the UK or must she apply for a new visitor visa?

Answer (score 0):

This document on "transitional provisions for visitors" seems to say that your wife's business visa now functions as a standard visitor visa:

https://www.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/423561/20150424_immigration_rules_part_2_final.pdf

Unfortunately, I wasn't able to find anything stating this more explicitly.